# have you seen? _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" being ignored

Tags: python, mysql

I am just starting out with the MySQLdb module for python, and upon running some SELECT and UPDATE queries, the following gets output:

> Exception
>   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL
>   server during query') in bound method Cursor.**del** of
>   MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x8c0188c ignored

The exception is apparently getting caught (and "ignored") by MySQLdb itself, so I guess this is not a major issue. Also, the SELECTs generate results and the table gets modified by UPDATE.

But, since I am just getting my feet wet with this, I want to ask: does this message suggest I am doing something wrong? Or have you seen these warnings before in harmless situations?

Thanks for any insight,

lara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha! Just realized I was trying to use the cursor *after* having closed the connection! In any case, it was nice writing! : )

l